# Changing WCF service to require SSL

Tags: wcf, ssl, binding, https, endpoint

I have a WCF service which was running fine on a http binding. I've tried to update this to use SSL but i am getting the following error:

"Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]."

This only occurs when i set the site to "Require SSL" in IIS 7.5 if I uncheck it it works fine.

Here's my config

```
<system.serviceModel>    
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WcfService1/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="MexHttpsBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I've tried allsorts and nothing seems to get me there, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your binding configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And reference that configuration in your `endpoint` by setting its `bindingConfiguration` attribute to the name of configuration.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
  name="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
```

You can also delete the `host` section with base address because it is not used when hosting in IIS.

Comment: I followed what you recommended and the service is now working on https! Thankyou very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing the binding configuration settings (as Ladislav mentioned)... Change HTTP in the base address to HTTPS.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I did have the base address set to https '<add baseAddress="https://localhost/WcfService1/"/>' still gets the same error though.

Comment: Can you please post your full binding after anonymising?